# Why is Illustrator CC saving my files as pdf?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have installed Illustrator CC and when i save a file it shows a pdf icon next to the file name the application bar. When i check file info, it says File info: application / pdf. Please help!

Comment: You have to select which file type you want to save as, when you open the Save As options, from the File menu...works pretty much the same in every program ever; how is this even a question?

Answer (score 2):

There could be many reasons, you  could have saved your file as a pdf, AI and PDF are very close format (PDF does not support external workspace stuff but the content should be the same ), you can actually even save an .PDF file that is AI compatible in the savebox. What you can do is drag your file into .AI and make sure you save an .EPS or .AI file. Manually change the extension from PDF to AI (Will ONLY WORK if the file was saved as editable ). Or, in windows, right click - Open as, and pick Adobe Illustrator.